# How can I display all values of a custom field from posts with a certain value of another custom field or from certain post types?

Tags: custom-field, list, meta-value

I know the question is quite ambiguous. Let me explain:

I have a page that lists all posts with a certain value of a custom field. 
(Eg.: The page `Rentals` lists all posts with the value `rental` of custom field `offer_type` ).

I'd like to add a filtering option by city, so that only posts with a certain value of `city` custom field get displayed. For this I created a form using the `get` method that builds a custom query (in my ex. with two custom fields, 'offer_type' and 'city').

**What I need** is a way to list all the cities (values of `city` custom field) for the posts with the `rental` value of `offer_type`. Each city has to be listed once.

I tried this bit of code (note that I took all the form wrapping out):

```
$metakey = 'city';
   $cities = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value 
           FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey) );

   if ($cities) {   
                 foreach ( $cities as $city ) {
                 echo $city;
            }
        }
```

but this lists all the values of `city` custom field for all the posts (so if for eg. I have a post with value of `offer_type` different than `rental`, its value of `city` custom field will be displayed in my list).

I know the issue revolves around sql queries and joining tables, but I really lack the skills to solve this problem.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the reference docs for the WP_Query class: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

something like this:

```
$args = array(
  //some key/value pairs...whatever
          'meta_query => array(
                          array(
                         'key' => somekey,
                         'value' => somevalue,
                         'compare' => some comparison operator
                         ),
                         array(
                         'key' => some other key,
                         'value' => some other value,
                         'compare' => some comparison operator
                         )
                     )
               )

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

//some code to do something with the results of the query
```

Comment: yes, I am familiar with the `meta_query` argument. But I don't know how can this help you my problem. I get all the posts I need, but how do I display only once all the values from a certain custom field? I did find an answer for a certain custom post-type here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/getting-all-values-for-a-custom-field-key-cross-post still looking for a solution for the first case (list of all custom field values from posts with a specific value of a different custom field) - I know, doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Using the meta_query arguments will populate the return object with everything you need to run a custom while have_posts() loop so you don't need to fuss with joining tables etc in your sql.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it seemed to work just fine until I bumped into another problem. What I did: I set up a custom query with 'meta_query' for two custom fields, I set up an empty array, then during a custom while have_posts() loop I populated it with the value of one of the custom fields. Then I `array_unique` the array and it seemed like problem solved. Bu then I realized there's a problem with pagination. The array contains only the values present on each page of the query. So I'm stuck again...

Answer (score 0):

this is not a direct answer to your question but a line of code you would use as reference to work onto.

here is a copy of what i use to search thru my table,
i search between a data range and then limit it to only display instances of an entered usr_id

```
 $this->items = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT  *  FROM $table_name WHERE `datec` BETWEEN CAST('$start_date' AS DATE) AND CAST('$end_date' AS DATE) AND `usr_id`= $usr_id"), ARRAY_A);
```

hope this helps :)