# How to get a meta value from all post

Tags: custom-field, wp-query

I searched for a while but I didn't find any solution. I used the functions [listed here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/getting-all-values-for-a-custom-field-key-cross-post).
It outputs something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 30
    [2] => 50
)
```

But I want something like this:

```
Array
(
    [post_id_1] => 15
    [post_id_2] => 30
    [post_id_3] => 50
)
```

And this is the $wp query that is used in the function:

```
function get_meta_values( $key = '', $type = 'post', $status = 'publish' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if( empty( $key ) )
        return;
    $r = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s' 
        AND p.post_status = '%s' 
        AND p.post_type = '%s'
    ", $key, $status, $type ) );
    return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`get_col()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Column) function returns only one column as array. To get two column result we can use [`get_results()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results), Which will return an array of objects

Which further can be converted into required structure using foreach loop.

**Example -**

```
function get_meta_values( $key = '', $type = 'post', $status = 'publish' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if( empty( $key ) )
        return;
    $r = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT p.ID, pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s' 
        AND p.post_status = '%s' 
        AND p.post_type = '%s'
    ", $key, $status, $type ));

    foreach ( $r as $my_r )
        $metas[$my_r->ID] = $my_r->meta_value;

    return $metas;
}
```

<sup>*( The modified version of your Example )*</sup>

Comment: When using `$wpdb->prepare` ([reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/)), you don't need to quote the placeholders, i.e. `p.post_status = '%s'` should be `p.post_status = %s`.

Comment: @amit how to add orderby pm.meta_key ASC in this. I am getting error after adding this

Answer (score 2):

WordPress have the function [get_metadata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata) this get all meta of object (Post, term, user...)

Just use

```
get_metadata( 'post', 15 );
```