# little help with a mySQL query to wp database

Tags: custom-field, mysql

[@t31os](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/31073/t31os) gave a very helpful response to:

[getting all values for a custom field key (cross-post)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/getting-all-values-for-a-custom-field-key-cross-post) by providing this function

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_meta_values' ) ) {
function get_meta_values( $key = '', $type = 'post', $status = 'publish' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if( empty( $key ) )
        return;
    $r = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s' 
        AND p.post_status = '%s' 
        AND p.post_type = '%s'
    ", $key, $status, $type ) );
    return $r;
}
}
```

(slightly adapted)

I need to adapt this function to retrieve not one but two columns; `meta_value` and `post_id`, both from the `postmeta` table and store these in an array.

I'm not knowledgeable at all with `mySQL`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean `SELECT pm.meta_value, pm.post_id FROM`?

Comment: is it that easy ? i feel silly !

Comment: You need `$wpdb->get_results()` instead of `$wpdb->get_col()`.

Comment: @toscho now it is retuning an array with the correct number of keys but all empty values...

Comment: @toscho i have found the answer based on your comments; being a new member i cant answer my own question for the next few hours though; i will share my response later. Thanks for your input!

Comment: You could update your question with the correct answer, then add the answer when you're able to.

Answer (score 1):

Following the recomendations of @toscho i had a look at get_results and the following edits to the function ended up doing the trick.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_meta_values' ) ) {
function get_meta_values( $key = '', $type = 'post', $status = 'publish' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if( empty( $key ) )
        return;
    $r = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT      pm.meta_value, pm.post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
        LEFT JOIN   {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE       pm.meta_key = '%s' 
        AND         p.post_status = '%s' 
        AND         p.post_type = '%s'
    ", $key, $status, $type ), ARRAY_A );
    return $r;
}
}
```

It only worked when i added the second parameter ARRAY_A (ARRAY_N or OBJECT(default) would have been possible too) to get_results() as per http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Thanks to everyone for their help.