# Get data from database using $WPDB

Tags: database, wpdb

I'm missing something here.
I simply want to get data from my database.
So I tried this but keeps giving me an error.

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE group='$group'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

foreach( $results as $result ) {

    echo $result->company_name;

}
```

`$group` is a parameter passed in the url the variable is `$group = $_GET['group'];`

This is the error:

> WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group='bicyclegroup'' at line 1]
>   SELECT * FROM xx_postmeta WHERE group='thegroup'
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group='thegroup'' at line 1

Can somebody please help me fix this once and for all so I can save it locally and use it for further projects :-)

Comment: the `or die( mysql_error() );` is bad, in newer versions of WordPress and PHP the mysql extension isn't even used ( the mysql extension and all the `mysql_` functions are deprecated in favour of `mysqli`, you should avoid them ). Instead check the value of `$results` and check for an error value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be because `group` doesn't exist in the postmeta table. Your *meta_key* is probably called **group** and has a *meta_value* of **bicyclegroup**. This is assuming you haven't modified the postmeta table. What you could try is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'group' AND meta_value='$group'";
```

This will return:

- meta_id
- post_id
- meta_key ( group )
- meta_value ( bicyclegroup )

---

Another option is to get all posts by post meta is a *secondary query* [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). To do so would look like this:

```
$test_posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key'       => 'group',
    'meta_value'     => $group
) );

<?php if( $test_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while( $test_posts->have_posts() ) : $test_posts->the_post(); ?>

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm not sure if you're using `post` are your post type so change that field accordingly.

Comment: I think I made a mistake in my thinking. I have the `wp_postmeta` table filled with different page attributes. I want to extract all other page attributes where the group is `$group`. So basically filter all pages that have the group `$group`.

Comment: @Interactive What you're looking for sounds like a WP_Query, one second let me write it up. Another option is you could use the `$post_id`'s that get returned from that SQL to then [`get_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post). Finally, another option is to modify the main query by using [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). You may be better off creating a new question and explaining your problem then show what you've tried to solve it ( you code above ).

Comment: This [answer to »getting all values for a custom field key (cross-post)«](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/9451/22534) offers an ready-made function for the `$wpdb` call, which can be customized for your use. @Interactive On a second thought, its not exactly what you want, but maybe helpful anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers and time. In the meantime I used `get_post` like you suggested. What would be wiser? Use the `get_post` or use your `WP_Query`?

Comment: @Interactive probably `WP_Query` - it's more powerful and it makes less DB calls, sounds what you're looking for - getting the actual posts.