# Display featured products through custom loop in woocommerce on template page

Tags: loop, woocommerce-offtopic, featured-post

I would like to display 6 featured products from my woocommerce store on my home-page.php template. After some researched I found that the right way to do this was through a custom loop,( I do not wish to use shortcodes because I would like to add additional classes for styling etc. ) I also found that the key that woocommerce uses for the featured products is '_featured'. I put together the code below to display any products that I chose to be featured products in my store, but it doesn't work... Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'product',
        'stock'       => 1,
        'showposts'   => 6,
        'orderby'     => 'date',
        'order'       => 'DESC' ,
        'meta_query'  => array(
            array(
                'key'     => '_featured',
                'value'   => 0,
                'compare' => '>',
                'type'    => 'numeric'
            )
        )
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

        <li>    
            <?php 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID ) ) 
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog' ); 
                else 
                    echo '<img src="' . woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() . '" alt="Placeholder" width="65px" height="115px" />'; 
            ?>
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

            <?php 
                echo $product->get_price_html(); 
                woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product );
            ?>    
        </li>

<?php 
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Comment: Add the result from `var_dump( get_meta_values( '_featured', 'product' );` where the function `get_meta_values` is supported by the custom function explained in [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/9451/31545)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change your args to be like this:

```
$meta_query   = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
$meta_query[] = array(
    'key'   => '_featured',
    'value' => 'yes'
);
$args = array(
    'post_type'   =>  'product',
    'stock'       =>  1,
    'showposts'   =>  6,
    'orderby'     =>  'date',
    'order'       =>  'DESC',
    'meta_query'  =>  $meta_query
);
```

If you go to wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php (@595) you can find how it's done for WC shortcodes.

Comment: They key to note is that '_featured' is not stored as a numeric value. It is stored as a string 'yes' or 'no'. Everything else in the OP question should work, worked for me.

Comment: As of WooCommerce 3.0, this solution no longer works. Please see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 25):

This has changed in WooCommerce 3.0. It's not simply a meta_query, but now includes a tax_query. The arguments are now:

```
    $meta_query  = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
    $tax_query   = WC()->query->get_tax_query();
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
        'field'    => 'name',
        'terms'    => 'featured',
        'operator' => 'IN',
    );

    $args = array(
        'post_type'           => 'product',
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'posts_per_page'      => $atts['per_page'],
        'orderby'             => $atts['orderby'],
        'order'               => $atts['order'],
        'meta_query'          => $meta_query,
        'tax_query'           => $tax_query,
    );
```

See woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php

Comment: Just what I was looking for!

Comment: Also for Woocommerce 3.0, they recommend using `wc_placeholder_img_src` instead of `woocommerce_placeholder_img_src`.

Answer (score 6):

Featured Products Loop in WooCommerce 3

```
<ul class="products">
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                'field'    => 'name',
                'terms'    => 'featured',
            ),
        ),
    );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    endwhile;
} else {
    echo __( 'No products found' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the [WooCommerce Wiki](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query):

> **Building custom WP_Queries or database queries [to retrieve products] is likely to break your code** in future versions of WooCommerce as data moves towards custom tables for better performance.

WooCommerce advocates using `wc_get_products()` or `WC_Product_Query()` instead of `WP_Query()` or `get_posts()`.

I've written a post with the code I used to achieve what you want here: https://cfxdesign.com/create-a-custom-woocommerce-product-loop-the-right-way/

Comment: sorry, without seeing some written code, it is hard to understand your article. Can you please include some coding ?

Comment: @HOY the embed plugin was broken; it's fixed now and you can see the code!

Comment: thank you, while looking for solutions, I came up with this one below. I am not sure how it differs from yours since I was not able to check yours throughly but it is very short and helped me with a custom product loop. https://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-modifying-product-query/

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite old, but I've just shared an alternative solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50081494/5970334) and I think it can help those reaching this topic too.

Instead of using `meta_query` or `tax_query`, you can use [wc_get_featured_product_ids()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_featured_product_ids.html) too:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'posts_per_page'      => 6,
    'orderby'             => 'date',
    'order'               => 'DESC',
    'post__in'            => wc_get_featured_product_ids(),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Based on: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query

I would try:

outside loop:

```
$args = array (
'limit' => 6,
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC',
'category' => $club_cat,
'stock_status' => 'instock',
'featured' => true,

 );

 $products = wc_get_products( $args );
```

in the loop:

```
$query = new WC_Product_Query( array(
'limit' => 6,
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC',
'category' => $club_cat,
'stock_status' => 'instock',
'featured' => true,
'return' => 'ids',

 ) );

 $products = $query->get_products();
```

Answer (score 1):

People should start using wc_get_products because woocommerce said this is the standard way of retrieving product. wc_get_products has an argument featured which just needs to be set to true. So the code is simply below.

```
 <?php 

// Display featured products by category. on this case its "shirts" which is the slug of the category.
$query_args = array(
    'featured' => true,  
    'category' => array( 'shirts' ),
);
$products = wc_get_products( $query_args );

global $post;
$columns = wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' );
?>
<div class="woocommerce columns-<?php echo esc_attr( $columns ); ?>">
  <?php
    woocommerce_product_loop_start();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $post = get_post($product->get_id());
        setup_postdata($post);
        wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    woocommerce_product_loop_end();
  ?>
</div>
```

See full post here: https://jameshwartlopez.com/plugin/get-featured-products-of-a-category/

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look in the database in `wp_postmeta` table you will see `meta_key` will be `_featured` and `meta_value` will be `yes` or `no` so instead of value `0` or `1` write `yes` or `no`

```
<?php
    $q = new WP_Query([
      'post_type'   =>  'product',
      'stock'       =>  1,
      'showposts'   =>  3,
      'orderby'     =>  'date',
      'order'       =>  'DESC',
      'meta_query'  =>  [ 
        ['key' => '_featured', 'value' => 'yes' ]
        ]
    ]);
    if ( $q->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post();
            // display product info
        endwhile; wp_reset_query();
    endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="products">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
            'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                        'field'    => 'name',
                        'terms'    => 'featured',
                    ),
                ),
            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
               echo '<p>'.get_the_title().'</p>';
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul><!--/.products-->
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Bump for 2021 - You need to be using [wc_get_products()](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)

Also, the code example from Jameshwart (above) didn't work for me, this is how I set up the postdata & use wc_get_template. Tested & working.

```
$args = array(
    'status' => 'publish',
    'limit' => 20,
    'paginate' => true, //must be true in order to get ->total
    'return' => 'ids',
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );

if ($products->total >= 1):

    woocommerce_product_loop_start();

    foreach($products->products as $pid):

        do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

        $product = get_post($pid);
        setup_postdata($GLOBALS['post'] =& $product);
        wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');

    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    woocommerce_product_loop_end();


endif; //we have products
```